# Procedure to copy data from a table to another table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table A, with 4 columns:
first_name, invoice, value, date.

And a table B (first_name, max_invoice_name, max_invoice_value, last_date)

I want to create a procedure in order to move data from A, to B, but:

first_name should be one time in B,
max_invoice_name is the name of the max invoice value
max_invoice_value is the max value
last_date is the latest date from invoices from the same first_name.

For example:
TABLE A:

```
Smith | Invoice1  | 100 | 23.06.2016
John  | Invoice13 | 23  | 18.07.2016
Smith | Invoice3  | 200 | 01.01.2015
```

Table B should be:

```
Smith |Invoice3 | 200 | 23.06.2016
John  |Invoice13| 23  | 18.07.2016
```

Comment: Actually I used a temporary table to keep all different first_names and then I read row by row. If exists in B => update with information from A, if not, insert a new row

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
select *, (select max(date) from #Table1 T1 where T1.first_name = X.first_name)
from (
  select
    *, 
    row_number() over (partition by first_name order by invoice_Value desc) as RN
  from
    #Table1
) X
where RN = 1
```

Row number takes care of selecting the row with biggest value, and the max get's the date. You'll need to list the columns in correct place instead of *

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create 2 scalar functions `getMaxNameForMaxValue` AND `getLastDateByFirstName` to get the values you want.

```
INSERT INTO TableB (first_name, max_invoice_name, max_invoice_value, last_date) (SELECT DISTINCT first_name, getMaxNameForMaxValue(MAX(max_value)) AS 'max_invoice_name', MAX(max_invoice_value) AS 'max_invoice_value', getLastDateByFirstName(first_name) AS 'lastDate' FROM Table A)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
--INSERT INTO TableB 
SELECT  first_name,
        invoice_name,
        invoice_value,
        last_date
FROM (
    SELECT  a.first_name,
            a.invoice_name,
            a.invoice_value,
            COALESCE(p.last_date,a.last_date) as last_date,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.first_name ORDER BY a.last_date) as rn
    FROM TableA a
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TableA WHERE first_name = a.first_name and last_date > a.last_date) as p 
) as res
WHERE rn = 1
```

As output:

```
first_name  invoice_name    invoice_value   last_date
John        Invoice13       23              2016-07-18
Smith       Invoice3        200             2016-06-23
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
Insert into TableB(first_name, max_invoice_name, max_invoice_value, last_date)
select t1.first_name,t1.invoice,t1,value,t2.date from TableA as t1 inner join
(
select first_name, max(replace(invoice,'invoice','')) as invoice, max(date) as date 
  from TableA group by first_name
) as t2 on t1.first_name=t2.first_name and t1.invoice=t2.invoice
```

Comment: First, there is probably syntax error. Second, result is wrong - consider having two invoices for same first_name, Invoice2 at 2016/01/01 and Invoice10 at 2016/02/02 - what you get in your inner select?